# Make Label Mask Entities Below It in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to draw a label in `cesium.js` over other entities, where the label background's trancparency masks the entities below.

Here is an example:
[image]

Tried to create a custom `Cesium.Material`, but failed doing so :(

Wondering if it's even possible?

Thanks :)